# Excel formula: Comparing current stock to goods received in previous months and anwer how old is the oldest stock

Tags: excel

Searching for the right formula to provide the anser in column H ="oldest Stock from"
Goods received in varios months. The formula should compare the current stock and calculate backwords on which month was the oldest stock received (assuming of course, that the first-in-first-out works)

[image]

Chat gpt could not help me, or i didn't manage to express my problem clearly enough

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution can be:
[image]

```
[H2]=OFFSET($A$1;0;MAX(MAP(SEQUENCE(1;6;0);LAMBDA(a;IF(SUM(OFFSET(A2;0;a):F2)>G2;a;0)))))
```

Fill this formula down.